# How to get all cities with their population laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

```
 $users = ApplicationPersonal::select(ApplicationPersonal::raw('count(*) as district'))
                                     ->groupBy('district')
                 ->get();
```

I need help in such query in laravel.

I want my data to be displayed as :

> City1 : 10 ppl
>
> City2 : 20 ppl
>
> City3 : 30 ppl

every city with its name and population.

My db has a city field associated for every user. I want to count how many user inside each city. So my data return to ajax would be Cities and population for each city.

Comment: What have you tried? When you say "displayed" how do you mean? You should give this a go yourself or provide a lot more info for this to be an answer-able question.

Comment: my db has a city field associated for every user . i want to count how many user inside each city . so my data return to ajax would be  Cities and population for each city @DBS

Comment: So you want to make an AJAX call and get the cities back in a certain structure? What part of that are you having trouble with? You need to narrow down the problem to something specific, this is Q&A site so don't expect the whole solution to be written for you.

Comment: Not expecting a whole solution , i just need a strategy for it . I tried to count users in every location then associate it with its location . But it is a long process , so i need a shorter one .

Comment: I know the Sql query , its counting users grouped by city .. But how to make it with laravel ? @DBS

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know, but this seems like a good place to start: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DB::table('tablename')->select('district', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                      ->groupBy('district')->get();
```

This was the solution for my problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try joining the tables? It seems that you have two tables (city and people). Then use `COUNT(city.name) FROM people_table`